# stuck at boot menu:No default or UI Config directive found

Tags: system-installation

Ok I downloaded the iso created a bootable usb with rufus but when I try to install on my desktop I don't get past the boot: menu.

sha256 checksum was ok and I triplechecked the rufus options - I used fat32 while the screenshot of instructions says FAT.

Whats up with this thing?

G0bble

Answer (score 0):

try with different kernel parameter such as nomodeset

F6 keys to select the options when you are on the live menu screen

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting it with a different filesystem and see the results. Maybe exFAT will work? It was what I used when installing Elementary OS.